# How can I merge an Array with an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having an array  of object

```
   var todos=  [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: test,
            description: test
        }
    ]
```

How can I insert an object with properties stored in different variable say

```
var newTodos={id:2,name:test2,description:test2,purpose:NA}
```

so that the final arrray looks like
var todos=

```
 [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: test,
        description: test
    },
    id: 2,
    name: test2,
    description: test2,
    purpose: NA
]
```

Comment: You can push onto an array with todos.push(newTodos.id), etc.

Comment: Do you really want to **extend** an array or push into it new object?

Comment: I am little confused, can an array contain a key:value pair like [purpose:NA] , etc.. ??

Comment: Your final array is invalid. Arrays do not (usually) contained named keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
for (var index in newTodos) {
    todos[index] = newTodos[index];
}
```

You can check the values of your array like this:

```
for (var index in todos) {
   console.log(index + ": " + todos[index]);
}
```

EDIT: In conform with the asked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c40sjdho/2/), I add the fiddle and code:

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">

  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
var todos=  [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test',
        description: 'test'
    }
];
var newTodos={id:2,name:'test2',description:'test2',purpose:'NA'};
for (var index in newTodos) {
    todos[index] = newTodos[index];
}
var output = "";
for (var index in todos) {
    if (typeof todos[index] === "object") {
        output += index + ": {";
        var first = true;
        for (var innerIndex in todos[index]) {
            if (!first) {
                output += ", ";
            } else {
                first = false;
            }
            output += innerIndex + ": " + todos[index][innerIndex];
        }
        output += "}<br>";
    } else {
        output += index + ": " + todos[index] + "<br>";
    }
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}

var alreadyrunflag = 0;

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alreadyrunflag=1; 
        VanillaRunOnDomReady();
    }, false);
else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');
    var contentloadtag = document.getElementById("contentloadtag")
    contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (this.readyState=="complete"){
            alreadyrunflag=1;
            VanillaRunOnDomReady();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout("if (!alreadyrunflag){VanillaRunOnDomReady}", 0);
}//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output">a</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: I strongly doubt that this is really what the OP wants to do. He doesn't seem to understand that arrays are composed of elements, and adding the properties of newTodo to the array is going to result in a mutant array that probably won't do what he wants.

Comment: This is an answer to the question. Op accepted the answer, therefore he was satisfied with it. In exact sciences we are working with facts, not with guesses.

Answer (score 1):

```
var todos=  [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: test,
            description: test
        }
    ]  
var newTodos={id:2,name:test2,description:test2,purpose:NA};
todos.push(newTodos);
```

Comment: Im not sure that this does what the question asks. This adds an object to the array. It does not merge the properties. Or I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Note, that this is not what OP is asking if he really wants to extend an array. It pushes new object into array.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you accepted is the right answer to the wrong question.

If you **really** want to add the properties of `newTodos` (which is misnamed; it is just a single todo) then you can do what the answer says, or more easily, just do

```
$.extend     (todos, newTodos);
_.extend     (todos, newTodos);
Object.assign(todos, newTodos);
```

or use your other favorite property merging utility.

However, I cannot imagine what you are going to usefully do with such a mutant object, which is an array with a single element which is a todo, and now is sort of a todo itself with the todo properties directly on it.

I'm guessing that what you want to do is add another todo to your array of todos, in which case as others have suggested you can just `push` it.

```
todos.push(newTodos)
```

If you actually mean `newTodos` to be an array of todos, as its name suggests, in other words, if its format is actually

```
var newTodos = [ {id:2,name:test2,description:test2,purpose:NA}, ... ];
```

Then to add it to todos you would concatenate:

```
todos = todos.concat(newTodos);
```